# inline c# code inside aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display different dropdown options based on the userName variable but not sure how to do this. Here's the code:

```
<form id="frmViewRequest" runat="server">
    <div class="widget-content">

       <div class="padd"><div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
             <% if (userName == "jpublic"){
                <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlChangeStatus">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Under Review" value="1" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
              }
              else{
                <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlChangeStatus">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Under Review" value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Approved" value="2" /> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="Rejected" value="3" /> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="Logged" value="4" /> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" value="5" /> 
               </asp:DropDownList>
               }
               %>
```

Is this possible? And if so, how would I show different ListItems based on the userName?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't declare multiple dropdownlist.

Instead, populate your dropdownlist in code-behind:

```
if (username == "jpublic")
   ddlChangeStatus.DataSource = ...;
else
   ddlChangeStatus.DataSource = ...;

ddlChangeStatus.DataTextField = ...;
ddlChangeStatus.DataValueField = ...;
ddlChangeStatus.DataBind();
```

Or with "static" data:

```
ddlChangeStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Under Review", "1"));
if (username != "jpublic")
{
   ddlChangeStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Approved", "2"));
   ddlChangeStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Rejected", "3"));
   ddlChangeStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Logged", "4"));
   ddlChangeStatus.Items.Add(new ListItem("Completed", "5"));
}
```

Comment: As I was answering the question specifically (inline c#), Justin's method is much preferred as you should be populating your dropdownlist in the code. Unless this is a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks @Papa I'll try Justin's solution.

Comment: If you explicitly only need the list items mentioned in the example, you could use the ddlChangeStatus.items.Add() method, rather than binding to a data source.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open/close each c# line.

```
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlChangeStatus">
<% if (userName == "jpublic"){ %>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Under Review" value="1" />
<% } else { %>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Under Review" value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Approved" value="2" /> 
            <asp:ListItem Text="Rejected" value="3" /> 
            <asp:ListItem Text="Logged" value="4" /> 
            <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" value="5" /> 
<% } %>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I get an error: "The ID 'ddlChangeStatus' is already used by another control." It sees the ID="ddlChangeStatus" in the if and the else. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Check my edit. Sorry bout that. Define the dropdownlist outside the if statement.